# PHP Regex for Accented Characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I try to filter a variable allowing alphanumeric ,spaces ,accented characters , and single quotes and replace the reste by a space , so a string like :

> substitué à une otage % ? vendredi 23 mars lors de l’attaque

should output :

> substitué à une otage vendredi 23 mars lors de l’attaque

but I get as Result the output :

> substitué à une otage vendredi 23 mars lors de l

could please help , this is my code

```
$whitelist = "/[^a-zA-Z0-9а-àâáçéèèêëìîíïôòóùûüÂÊÎÔúÛÄËÏÖÜÀÆæÇÉÈŒœÙñý',. ]/";

$descreption =  preg_replace($whitelist, ' ', $ds);
}else{
    $errors = self::DESCREPTION_ERROR;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Depends on the encoding. `/u` Unicode flag usually for the regex. Also `’` and `'` are different characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is faulty. The part `а-à` gives the error `Character range is out of order` - I guess the `-` was added by mistake there...

Then a small hint: `’` is not `'`

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9àâáçéèèêëìîíïôòóùûüÂÊÎÔúÛÄËÏÖÜÀÆæÇÉÈŒœÙñý'’,. ]
```

should work fine.

Also, if you're working with Regex, tools like [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) or [regex101](https://regex101.com/) are really a nice thing.

Comment: thanks @maio290 for your response , but a string like : masculin  de deux $%#$^%$&^dbd657657657*&()*)_()+!#!@#±?/  du paysage cultuel actuel. , it removes "du paysage cultuel actuel"

Comment: It doesn't here. And nor does it match on RegExr or regex101. It's not removing the ± - but that was it.

Answer (score 1):

One way to deal with the range of accented characters is to use the POSIX `[:alnum:]` class, which in PHP in conjunction with the `u` modifier will match all of them. That can then be put into a negated character class with the other characters you want to keep to allow the other characters to be removed:

```
$string = 'substitué à une otage % ? vendredi 23 mars lors de l’attaque';
echo preg_replace("/[^[:alnum:]'’,.]/u", ' ', $string);
```

Output:

```
substitué à une otage vendredi 23 mars lors de l’attaque
```

As has been pointed out in the comments, `’` is not the same as `'` and so it also needs to be added to the set of characters you want to keep.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/9hoKa)

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at [Unicode character properties](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php).

Summary of my changes:

- use `\p{L}` to match all letters
- escape the hyphen (`\-`)
- support typewriter (`'`) and typographic (`’`) apostrophes

Here is the result:

```
$whitelist = '/[^\p{L}0-9\-\'’,. ]/u';
```

There is probably room for even further improvement. Finally, don't forget to add the `u` [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)!